# Class not found error for a class in the same namespace as the caller

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I am a bit confused about this, as it's got to be something extremely simple.

I have the following structure:

**class X:**

```
namespace A;
use \B\Y;

class X
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $y = new Y();
    }
}
```

**class Y:**

```
namespace B;

class Y
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $z = new Z();
    }
}
```

**class Z:**

```
namespace B;

class Z
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**main program:**

```
namespace A;

$x = new X();
```

As you can see, classes Y and Z are in the same namespace, while class A is in a different namespace (which is the same as the main program)

When I try to execute this main program, I get error message `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Z' not found`.

If I debug it the program and put a breakpoint inside the autoloader, I can see that class Y is being loaded as \B\Y, yet class Z is being loaded without the namespace qualifier (it's being used inside another class from the same namespace).  The question is, why is class Z being loaded without the namespace qualifier?

I have quite a few class in namespace B, all referencing each other without the namespace qualifier - and it would be quite painful (but not impossible) to go change them all.

Comment: In your example, class `Z` is actually called `Y`. I've tested your sample (with fixed class Z) and it seems to work fine with a basic autoload function:

Comment: @Pieter Yeah, it should be Z, copy/paste error.  Then why in the autoloader (and I admit, it's a custom autoloader to deal with project-specific issues) the requested class name does not have the namespace?

Comment: Without providing the actual autoloader code, I can't tell you. With this autoloader it does work: `spl_autoload_register(function($class) { require_once __DIR__ . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php'; });` (assuming you use PSR-0 with your project structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very interesting indeed.  What I found was this.  In my case, the name of the class is read from an external source, something like this:

```
$className = "Segment_" . $element->getName();
$segment = new $className();
```

This failed, complaining that the class was not found and, when stepped through the autoloader, showed that the class being requested did not contain the namespace.  I changed this code to this one:

```
$className = __NAMESPACE__ . "\Segment_" . $element->getName();
$segment = new $className();
```

And this worked fine.

I supposed, for a dynamic class names, PHP was not prepending the current namespace and it had to be manually added.